# SwiftUI Picker doesn't work with array returned from function

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to get a picker to select dimensions which I want to return from a function based on a name.  When I return the array of allowed dimensions from a function, the picker no longer works - it doesn't set the selection.  It does work if I use a hard coded array of dimensions (which I really don't want to do).  Here's a quick example (not the real code) that shows my problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    static let Dimensions = [UnitLength.meters, UnitLength.yards, UnitLength.feet]
    
#if true
    let dimensions = Self.Dimensions
#else
    let dimensions = Self.getDimensions()
#endif
    
    @State var dimension = UnitLength.meters
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Picker("Dimensions", selection: $dimension)
        {
            ForEach(dimensions, id: \.self)
            {
                dimension in
                
                Text(dimension.symbol)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
    }
    
    static func getDimensions() -> [Dimension]
    {
        Self.Dimensions
    }
}
```

When the #if at the top is true, the code works.  When it is false, it does not work.  Any idea why?  Adding a .tag(dimension) didn't make any difference.

I do get an error/warning in the debug console when #if is false:

> Picker: the selection "<_NSStatic_NSUnitLength: 0x1f58b3aa8> m" is
> invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined
> results.

Printing dimensions in both cases appears to give the same array.

I'm using Xcode 15.2 and testing with the simulator on iOS 17.2.

Comment: Don’t you get a compilation error from the function or what is Dimension defined as?

Comment: Dimension is defined in Foundation - it inherits from Unit and NSSecureCoding.

Comment: Thanks, my googling failed me :). The type for your select property must be the same as the array elements so if your function returns an array of `Dimension` then the property must be declared as `@State var dimension: Dimension = UnitLength.meters`. Or use `UnitLength` everywhere instead as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the return type of the function `getDimensions` to `[UnitLength]`:

```swift
static func getDimensions() -> [UnitLength] {
    Self.Dimensions
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the type of the static array to `[Dimension]` and then use a state variable that is also of type `Dimension`:

```swift
static let Dimensions: [Dimension] = [UnitLength.meters, UnitLength.yards, UnitLength.feet]

@State var dimension: Dimension = UnitLength.meters
```